# How to return state of media player?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to return the current state of the media player because I want to check that the media player has not loaded a song yet so I can provide a popup to choose an audio file.

**Code in other class**

```
public Sound(int buttonID, Activity _activity) {
        super();
        this.activity = _activity;
        button = (Button) activity.findViewById(buttonID);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
    }
```

**Code to check if an audio file is loaded**

```
sound.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(//no audio file loaded){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST);
                }
                else if(sound.mp.isPlaying()) {
                    sound.mp.pause();
                }
                else{
                    sound.mp.seekTo(0);
                    sound.mp.start();
                }
            }


        });
```

Using the answer, this is the code I came up with:

```
sound.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sound.mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        isPrepared = true;
                    }
                });

                if(!isPrepared){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST);
                }
                else if(sound.mp.isPlaying()) {
                    sound.mp.pause();
                }
                else{
                    sound.mp.seekTo(0);
                    sound.mp.start();
                }
            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is no such method. You have to check it yourself. It's not too hard to follow `MeidaManager` state with the [MediaPlayer's StateDiagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). The easiest way is to declare a `boolean` flag `isPrepared / isReadyToPlay` and set it to `true` in `onPrepared()` callback of the OnPreparedListener.

Comment: I'm thinking about loading a dummy file and then checking if that's there in order to overwrite it. That wouldn't be elegant though would it? Or how would I weave in the onpreparedlistener with your solution?

Comment: you have to re-prepare `MediaManager` whenever you change your sound data source( `url`/`uri`). There's no another way.

Comment: So where would I put the onpreparedlistener?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following could help...

```
MediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(...);

  public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent)
  {
    //while MediaPlayer's buffer been update
  }

MediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(...);

  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
  {
    //while MediaPlayer is ready to play
  }

MediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(...);

  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
  {
    //while MediaPlayer played to the end
  }

MediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(...);

  public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)
  {
    //while MediaPlayer has error ocurred
  }
```

Also, your class must implement OnAudioFocusChangeListener, and create the following method

```
public boolean requestAudioFocus()
{}

public boolean abandonAudioFocus()
{}

public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange)
{}
```

You may considered to put your MediaPlayer into a Service class.